# How to use css to restrict scrollable width of a div in browser

Tags: css

I will like to know how I can use CSS to restrict the scrollable width of a page, when the browser is not maximized. A typical example can be found at the landing page at http://www.lynda.com/

When the browser is maximized the picture of the lady in the couch has some space at the left and right but when the browser area is reduced you realize that you are not able to scroll to the extreme left and right.

I am trying to achieve a similar layout at http://www.lynda.com/ with the code below but my image gets clipped off on the rightside when I reduce the browser window and scroll to the right.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 

charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="ave.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="gh.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
<div id="bigpicturecontainer"></div><!--image size is 1600px x 

400px and can be downloaded here 

http://www.ghanabuildingplans.com/trial.png
-->

<div id="bigmessage">Content for  id &quot;bigmessage&quot; 

Goes Here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my css code is:

```
#bigpicturecontainer {
background-color: #000;
background-image: url(images/trial.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: center center;
height: 400px;
width: 100%;
}
#bigmessage {
height: 45px;
width: 900px;
border-top-width: 0px;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-right-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
margin-top: 50px;
font-size: 36px;
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

I have found the solution! All I needed to do was to set the min-width.

Comment: That example looks like they've got a fixed width image and a black background. The image blends with the background because of the black edges. Here is the [image](http://cdn.lynda.com/assets/197-r20131102/Website/ui/images/LayoutNMHP/hero-image-tablet-couch.jpg).

Comment: Have to you done any of your own research or just straight away landed here?

Answer (score 1):

It is a background-image infront of a background. The women you see, is this picture:
http://cdn.lynda.com/assets/197-r20131102/Website/ui/images/LayoutNMHP/hero-image-tablet-couch.jpg
You see the transition to black on the side. Than behind this `background-image` there is a `background` which is just black.

```
background-image: url(../../images/LayoutNMHP/hero-image-tablet-couch.jpg);
background: #000
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Answer (score 0):

This very picture you're talking about is embeded in the website as a CSS property `background-image`. Its visibility depends on the element it is embeded in. In that case in `.hero` div. This div has fixed height. The width is 100% by default. The image is positioned in the center of that div. No matter what the window viewport is, the image will always fit in the `.hero` div. It can't affect that div as a result can't force the website to overflow *outside* the window.
A shortcut CSS of such picture might look like this:

```css
.hero {
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url(http://cdn.lynda.com/assets/197-r20131102/Website/ui/images/LayoutNMHP/hero-image-tablet-couch.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the prompt answer. I am most grateful. Its good to have guys like you to help us (novice) along every step of the way.